# python homework interleaving list

Tags: python

The problem statement is:

> Design and implement an algorithm that displays the elements of a list
> by interleaving an element from the beginning and an element from the
> end.

For example, input:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
```

Output :

```
1 8 2 7 3 6 4 5
```

This is what I tried, but I don't know what happen with elements 7 and 8:

```
lista = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]

for i in range(len(lista)):
  lista.insert(2*i-1,lista.pop())

print("The list after shift is : " + str(lista))

# output:
# The list after shift is : [1, 7, 2, 8, 3, 6, 4, 5]
```

Comment: You have poorly explained. Tell what is your current output and input and what is your desired output.

Comment: It's because when you do 2*i-1, it's evaluated as ((2*0)-1) = (0-1) = -1. So, you pop 8, and insert at position -1, which is the penultimate position. Likewise, when i = 1, you pop 7 and add at position ((2*1)-1) = (2-1) = 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only error in you code, is that `range(len(lista))` starts from `0`, not from `1`. By starting from zero, in the first iteration `2*i-1` will be `2*0-1 = -1`, and hence `lista.insert(-1,lista.pop())`, which means inserting at the very end of the list (that is what index `-1` means in python).

To fix your code, you just need to start the range from `1`. Actually, you are iterating too much, you can have your range just from 1 to the half of your list, like this:

```
lista = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
for i in range(1, len(lista)//2):
  lista.insert(2*i-1,lista.pop())

print("The list after shift is : " + str(lista))

# output:
# The list after shift is : [1, 8, 2, 7, 3, 6, 4, 5]
```

---

When you become more familiarized with the language, you will see that this can be accomplished much more easily.

For example, you can use the python slice syntax to achieve your goal. You slice from beginning to half , and from end to half (step of -1), then zip then together and flat.

```
[i for z in zip(lista[:4],lista[:-5:-1]) for i in z]
# [1, 8, 2, 7, 3, 6, 4, 5]
```

Comment: Your first slice inside zip _could_ be `lista[:4]` (it's working as it's now because zip stops at the shortest list). Of course, you could also get the length dynamically.

Comment: thank you so much, until now I had thought that it started at i=1

Answer (score 0):

Another option:

```
import math

lista = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]

ans = []
for i in range(math.floor(len(lista)/2)):
    ans.append(lista[i])
    ans.append(lista[-i-1])


if (len(lista) % 2) != 0:
    ans.append(lista(math.ceil(len(lista)/2)))

print(ans)
```

Answer (score 0):

Technically speaking, I'd say it's two off-by-one errors *(or one off-by-one error, but from -1 to +1, you'll see what I mean in the second paragraph)*. The first one is that you're subtracting 1 when you shouldn't. In the case when i = 0 (remember that `range(n)` goes from `0` to `n-1`), the insert position is being evaluated as `2*0-1` = `(2*0)-1` = `0-1`= `-1` (for `insert()` method, that's the last position of the original list, pushing what was there forward, so it'll be the penultimate position of the NEW list).

But, when you remove the -1, the output becomes `8 1 7 2 6 3 5 4`, which is *close* to what you want, but not quite right. What's missing is that the elements inserted should be at positions 1, 3, 5, 7, and not 0, 2, 4, 6. So, you'll actually need to **add** 1.

So, the shortest change to fix your code is to change `lista.insert(2*i-1,lista.pop())` to `lista.insert(2*i+1,lista.pop())`.

*Notice: if you put a print inside **for**, you'll realize that, after changing half the elements, the output is already right. That's because when len(lista) is 8, and you do `lista.insert(x, lista.pop())` where x is bigger than 8, basically you're removing the last element (pop) and adding it at the end, so, nothing changes. Hence, you could also change range(len(lista)) to range(len(lista)//2). **Test if it'll work when len(lista) is odd***

Comment: Actually, -1 is the last position, not penultimate

Comment: That's true, but not for insert. I'll add that. Edit: found out why. `insert(i, x)` inserts at position i, pushing what were there and everything after it. So, insert(-1, x) will insert at the last position, but push the last element. So, in this case, `lista` will have 7 elements (after pop), it'll insert at position 7, but push the 7th element to position 8

Comment: I figured out the confusion. I was thinking in terms of the NEW list, not the original list.